# how to pass object into onclick method at thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to add a onclick function for the element  at thymeleaf, here is my code:

```
<a th:each="item: ${unStableCaseList}" class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:text="${item.category}" th:onclick="|switchTable('${unStableCaseList}')|"></a>
```

It works, but the object `${unStableCaseList}` passed in to the function `switchTable` is not a "object" instead of plain string.

Is there anyway to pass a object inside the function?

I know it will work if create a javascript block like the following inside the html page
    
        var tmp = [[${unStableCaseList}]]

But I would like to keep the function `switchTable` outside of the html page, so any idea how can I achieve it?

Br,

Tim

Comment: you could parse the object into json within your controller.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. This is a option, but i would prefer pass the obj directly, so far, it seems this is not possible.

Comment: I think it is possible, but you have to extend the "th"-dialect.